# Best Resources on Getting Started?

Tags: beer, nutrition

I have several food allergies and a big one is malt. Because I thirst for a good beer once in a while and the difficulty of finding beer I can drink, I am entertaining the idea of brewing my own beer. What are some of the best online resources and/or books on getting started?

Answer (score 3):

This site, for one. As you learn more, you'll have more questions. Be sure to ask us.

The term you're going to want to search for is `gluten free` or `sorghum`. Those are the ingredients I'm guessing you're looking for.

[HomebrewTalk.com](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/) is a great resource for all things brewing.

[Brew Your Own](http://byo.com) magazine has some articles about gluten free brewing.

[Bard's Tale Brewing](http://www.bardsbeer.com/) makes gluten free beer. They can be a good resource as well.

And of course, your local homebrew shop, depending on where you are, should have some excellent resources both in paper and brain form.

I did a little research on this on my own, and it was hard to find very much out there. Please share what you find!

Answer (score 1):

There are a vast array of gluten free beers you can make with alternative fermentable resources, like quinoa, buckwheat, sorghum, rice and maize.  This sounds like a really fun project.  I recommend looking into African opaque beers.  Nigeria had a restriction on the importation of barley in 1986 and many brewers were forced to utilise sorghum.  There might be some good recipe suggestions from that debacle, and I know opaque beer remains popular in South Africa.  If you are thirsty now or want something to sip on while making your homebrew I can recommend RedBridge.  It is a sorghum beer brewed by Anheuser-Busch.  Have fun and best of luck!